# SPSS finding the significands between age_group and primary device of choice?

Tags: regression, correlation, statistical-significance, spss

I am trying to find a correlation between age group and primary device of choice, and then also compute a statistical significant.

Here's my output in SPSS,

[image]

I have grouped the data in this way:

[image]

This grouping isn't random, it was made this way, because I conducted an online questionnaire, where respondents were free to select their age group, instead of sharing their age directly. Now, if this was a mistake, it is too late to go back and email out to 50 people and ask them to redo the questionnaire.

What can be done for this to work and make sense?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have 40 cases, where 22 have desktop as primary device and 18 have mobile as primary device, and that you've set up the data with three variables. What you want is two variables, age (group) and primary device, with two values for the primary device variable, one value for those with desktop as primary device, another for those with mobile as primary device. Then you can correlate the two variables. The CROSSTABS procedure (Analyze>Descriptive Statistics>Crosstabs in the menus) produces a variety of measures of association and correlation for such data.